# Get values from selected row in a GridEx

Tags: vb.net, winforms, gridex

I have a Gridex with one column as a link column. When a user clicks a link the event triggered should then store several values from the selected row in several different variables.

I suppose the values could also be stored in the same variable if necessary. I do however need to get several values from the GridEx, getting just the value of the clicked link isn't going to work for my use case.

I'm sure it's a simple one liner but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've found an answer to my question. This seems to work for me

```
Dim Row1 As Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEXRow
        Row1 = GridEXSORCodes.CurrentRow

            frmGeneric.Var = Row1.Cells("Column").Value.ToString
            frmGeneric.Var = Row1.Cells("Column").Value.ToString
```